# Using Jquery Reset 2nd form when any change is made to first form.

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

I have two forms on my site (one is woocommerce, the other is gravity forms). The first form contains a single drop down with two options. The 2nd form contains two drop down fields. Any time the first form changes I want the second form to reset. I know this sounds strange but its for a hack. So I need a change function and clear form function. Lets say that a user selects option 1 from the first form then selects an option in each of the fields in form 2, the user then decides to select option 2 from the first form. The second form needs to reset.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

Try something on the lines of this:

```
<form id="first">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="second">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="a">Option A</option>
    <option value="b">Option B</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="c">Option C</option>
    <option value="d">Option D</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Bind the `change` event handler to the `<select>` in the `#first` form:

```
$('#first select').change(function(){
  $('#second select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

The `change` callback then sets all `<select>` elements property in the `#second` form to the first `<option>`

See http://jsfiddle.net/cC9sb/1/ for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Cue's answer, you could simple use

Javascript

```
$('#first select').change(function(){
  $('#second')[0].reset();
});
```

The line  `$('#second')[0].reset();` will reset all the elements in the form (if you ever were to have inputs (text, radio, checkboxes...)).

HTML

```
<p>Form 1</p>
<form id="first">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p>Form 2</p>
<form id="second">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="a">Option A</option>
    <option value="b">Option B</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="c">Option C</option>
    <option value="d">Option D</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Cue's updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC9sb/2/)

Comment: Good shout on the `.reset()` - I completely overlooked the `<form>` element!